# React Native - How to prevent full screen video mode in IOS?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, html5-video

I am creating a simple video app using the `react native` for `IOS`. But the problem is that when i play the video the video is played in the full screen mode, even if I set the property `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` to `true` but still no impression. Please can anyone tell why we use the `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` property and how to enable the inline video mode in `IOS`?

Even i added the `webkit-playsinline` attribute to the `HTML video` tag as well but which is documented (as following) on the `react native` website but still not working.

> **NOTE:**
>
> In order for video to play inline, not only does this property need to
> be set to true, but the video element in the HTML document must also
> include the webkit-playsinline attribute.

Please take a look at the following links:

- [Documentation Reference For WebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#allowsinlinemediaplayback).
- [Working Source Code](https://snack.expo.io/@sunnykhan/sharp-mind).

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply remove `webkit` prefix from `webkit-playsinline` because `webkit` prefix is no longer required nor it is supported.

Following is the correct and modified code snippet of your code you shared in the question:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView, View } from 'react-native';

export default class MyVideoApp extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={{
                flex: 1,
                flexDirection: 'column',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center'
            }}>
                <WebView
                source={{
                    html: '<video playsinline controls autoplay src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" ></video>'
                }}
        useWebKit={true}
                originWhitelist={['*']}
                allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
                style={{
                    height: 600,
                    width: 400,
                }}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the authors of `react native` website didn't provide this information to not use the `webkit` prefix. In fact the `webkit` prefix is documented on the `react native` official website. Take a look at the warning in the `yellow` container here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#allowsinlinemediaplayback

Answer (score 1):

enter "playsInline" in your video tag